# Angular: how to post a file to the server on form submit

Tags: angularjs, spring, kotlin, spring-web

I have a form that's being posted to my back-end (Kotlin, Spring Web). That form had some text inputs and the post worked flawlessly. But when I added a file input, the post stopped working, returning the following error:

```
{status: 400, error: "Bad Request",…}
error: "Bad Request"
exception: "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException"
message: "Could not read document: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.test.InsertConfigCommand]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)↵ at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2cb43211; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.test.InsertConfigCommand]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)↵ at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2cb43211; line: 1, column: 2]"
```

Here are the codes of my stack:

**View:**

```
<form ng-submit="insert(config)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="config.name">
    <input type="text" ng-model="config.address">
    <input type="file" ng-model="config.file">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

**Controller (front-end):**

```
$scope.insert = function (config) {
    $http.post('/config', config)
        .then(function (response) {
            $.snackbar({content: "Success!"});
        }, $scope.showErrorMessage);
};
```

**Controller (back-end):**

```
@RequestMapping(method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST))
fun insert(@RequestBody config: InsertConfigCommand) = service.save(config)
```

**InsertConfigCommand**

```
data class InsertConfigCommand (
    val name : String = "",
    val address : String = "",
    val file : MultipartFile
)
```

I've tried to do the post the following way, it works, but only sends the file:

**Controller (front-end):**

```
$scope.insert = function (file) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);

    return $http.post('/config', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
        }
    });
};
```

**Controller (back-end):**

```
@RequestMapping(method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST))
fun insert(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = true) file: MultipartFile) = service.save(file)
```

What do I need to change for this post to work? I want to send the input file **on the same object** that the name and address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this tutorial which encapsulates the file inside the FormData object, and posts that object https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

```
$scope.insert = function (config) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('name', config.name);
    fd.append('address', config.address);
    fd.append('file', $scope.file);
    $http.post('/config', fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            $.snackbar({content: "Success!"});
        }, $scope.showErrorMessage);
};
```

And on my Kotlin controller, I receive each attribute as a separate param:

```
@RequestMapping(method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST))
fun insert(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) name: String,
           @RequestParam(value = "address", required = true) address: String,
           @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) file: MultipartFile): InsertConfigCommand? {

    val command = InsertConfigCommand(
                   name = name,
                   address = address,
                   file = file)

    return service.save(command)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using Jackson, right?

Bytecode of Data Classes in Kotlin looks differently than one of a regular POJO (with default constructor) and so Jackson is unable to initialize such class. Try to add a dependency to [Jackson Kotlin Module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) and make sure to register it.

If you use Spring Boot then add following code to any of your @Configuration annotated classes:

```
@Bean
open fun kotlinModule(): KotlinModule {
    return KotlinModule()
}
```

and see if it helps.

Comment: Sorry, it did not work. I don't think that it's a Jackson problem, because when I do the post without the file param, the parse works.